# Laravel file upload creating folder with file name

Tags: laravel-5, laravel-5.5

I have probably just been staring at this too long and its right in front of me. I am trying to upload PDF documents. When I do it uploads to /storage/resumes/{hash}.pdf/{hash}.pdf  instead of /storage/resumes/{hash}.pdf

Its creating an extra folder with the same name as the file.

```
public function update(Request $request)
{
    $user = Auth::user();
    $this->validate($request, ['resume' => 'required|mimes:pdf|max:2048']);
    $file = $request->file('resume');
    $path = $file->hashName('resumes');
    $disk = Storage::disk('public');
    $disk->put($path, $file);
   $oldResumeUrl = $user->resume;
   $user->forceFill(['resume' => $disk->url($path)])->save();
   if (preg_match('/resumes\/(.*)$/', $oldResumeUrl, $matches)) {
      $disk->delete('resumes/'.$matches[1]);
   }

   $request->user()->forceFill([
      'resume' => $request->resume,
      'resume_updated_at' => Carbon::now()
   ])->save();
 }
```

What did I do wrong?

Comment: So, where is the question?

Answer (score 0):

Like I said earlier, I had just been staring at it too long. I was writing to the database twice.. once with the right answer... and one with the wrong.

RIGHT:

```
$user->forceFill(['resume' => $disk->url($path)])->save();
```

WRONG:

```
 $request->user()->forceFill([
  'resume' => $request->resume,
```